# How to convert PDF's with footnotes for Kindle?

Tags: kindle, epub, calibre, pdf, conversion

I have a collection of `PDF` files which I'm looking to load onto a `Kindle`.  First, however, they need to be converted.

Experimentation gives sub-par results by selecting and converting to `mobi` through `calibre`.  Better results are achieved by copy/paste to a text file.  I haven't yet tried a bulk convert to text from `calibre`.

Some `PDF`'s have very odd results, where what's visually and logically a paragraph of text is somehow "columns" either when copy/pasted or converted.  The result is a sort of interlace, but slightly out of sequence.  However, that's unusual.  For the most part/copy past gives excellent results.

These `PDF`'s generally are all text, with footnotes.

It's a bit mystifying why copy/paste would be better than calibre converting to `mobi`.

Answer (score 1):

PDFs are not designed to be converted from. They have no structure that allows Calibre to determine for sure how many columns of text it has or what's a footnote. The [Calibre manual](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/conversion.html#pdfconversion) describes the topic in more depth.

I found that copying the text to a text editor, cleaning it up and then pasting it into the Calibre e-book editor gives the best results but it takes long and is boring.  I've written down my work-flow in a [blog post](https://thoughtpile.tastytea.de/posts/how-i-convert-pdfs-to-epub/). It describes how to make EPUBs, but I'm sure it can be adapted to mobi fairly easily, since it seems to use XHTML too.